# Copy from another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm very new to excel therefore I have a lot of questions.

I have two workbooks I need to work with. I have a workbook with different names and other information. Each name matches another name in a different workbook. 
Wb1:

```
╔═══╦════════════╗
║ A ║    B       ║
╠═══╬════════════╣
║ 1 ║ Name1      ║
║ 2 ║ Name2      ║
║ 3 ║ Name3      ║
╚═══╩════════════╝
```

Wb2

```
╔═══════╦════════════╗
║ A     ║    B       ║
╠═══════╬════════════╣
║ Name1 ║ Name5      ║
║ Name2 ║ Name6      ║
║ Name3 ║ Name7      ║
╚═══════╩════════════╝
```

I want the code to loop through workbook 2, and if it finds for example "Name 1" it should copy "Name5" from columb B into workbook1 Column c.

Comment: Thank you. One more question if I have an ifstatmen like this  

=IF( A1=B1"OK";"NOT OK")

And i also want it to return blank cell if A1 or B1 is empty how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `VLOOKUP()` function for this. Add this formula to the cell in column C and pull it down. Just alter the ranges and names to your exact situation.

```
=VLOOKUP(B4;[Book2]Sheet1!$A$1:$B$3;2;0)
```

I also have an extra formula that will display nothing if the name isn't found. Otherwise it will display #N/A.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B4;[Book3]Sheet1!$A$1:$B$3;2;0);"")
```

**EXTRA**: depending on your country settings it's possible you need to change `;` for `,`